# How do I forward my domain's traffic to my WordPress.com hosted blog

Tags: domains, wordpress, domain-registration, traffic

I own a domain e.g. `myname.com` but host my blog with `wordpress.com` e.g. `myname.wordpress.com`.

Can I forward the traffic visiting my domain name to my `wordpress.com` blog so that when my friends look for my site using Google they easily find the content of my blog?

A step by step tutorial would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Poor Man's method,  you can add a URL Frame in `myname.com` to load the content from `myname.wordpress.com` depending of your nameservers panel/ownership/possible customization.

The real WordPress supported config is the paid one called domain mapping.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/.

Comment: hi @jflaflamme : Many Thanks your ideas is helpful. but I heard an issued that if we use iframe SEO will flow to the myname.wordpress.com.. is that right.?

Comment: Yes i heard that also, but it wasn't the question asked , i suggest you to ask a new question with this and tag it as seo

Comment: Okey nice suggest

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a htaccess file in the root of myname.com containing a 301 redirect like this

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myname\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://myname.wordpress.com [R=301,L]
```

If the file doesn't exist it should be called `.htaccess`

This does depend on what kind of server your domain is hosted on.

Comment: hi @toomanyairmiles, if redirected i want to make it that myname.wordpress.com is not shown in address bar.. can i make if redirected just show in adress bar myname.com not instead myname.wordpress.com... Thanks

Comment: Well, the only way to do that would be a framed forward, but that would hit the google ranking

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the common methods of informing your visitor about your new blog. Simply post a notice board on your old website or domain. Always Post it at the top of your blog or below your menu so that visitors can see your Advertisements without any issue. Also make it attractive so that, it can grab the attention of visitors.